a Spring Boot project executing mvn clean install in different directories, the result of executing java -jar is different
I have a Spring Boot project, and after executing mvn clean install in the /home/workspace directory on Linux as well as in other directories, the result of executing java -jar is different.
when I  executing mvn clean install in the /home/workspace directory, Details are shown in the picture
enter image description here
enter image description here
If I rename the workspace to "workspac1" or any other name that is not "workspace", and then execute "mvn clean install" and "java -jar", the application starts normally. Please see the details in the image below.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Would /home/workspace cause this issue? I'm very puzzled.
I tried cloning the Git code in different paths, and only encountered this issue when cloning it under /home/workspace.
my environment, jdk version and mvn version
[root@cloud home]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
[root@cloud home]# mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 1.8.0_221, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_221/jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
the parent pom.xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.highgo.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudplatform</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <modules>
            <module>cloudnative</module>
            <module>cloudservice</module>
            <module>common</module>
            <module>logger</module>
            <module>authcenter</module>
      </modules>
    
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
            <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
            <spring-boot.version>2.3.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
            <mapstruct.version>1.5.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
            <lombok.version>1.18.16</lombok.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <!--Spring boot -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <!--Spring boot Web-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <!--lombok-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
    
            <!--mapStruct-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!--swagger-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
    </project>

the module pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>cloudplatform</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.highgo.cloud</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>cloudservice</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>highgo cloud database service</description>

    <properties>
        <groovy.version>3.0.10</groovy.version>
        <commons.lang3.version>3.9</commons.lang3.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.authorization.version>0.3.1</spring.authorization.version>
        <druid.version>1.1.24</druid.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.highgo.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>authcenter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.highgo.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--jwt-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${druid.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added HuaweiCloud Begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.huawei</groupId>
            <artifactId>openstack4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.26</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.huaweicloud.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>huaweicloud-sdk-ecs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.63</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added HuaweiCloud End -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--begin pay order for prePaid -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.huaweicloud.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>huaweicloud-sdk-bss</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.68</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>huaweicloud-sdk-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.huaweicloud.sdk</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--end pay order for prePaid -->
        <!--begin commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--begin email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--begin email -->
        <!--begin retry-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>25.1-jre</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>kubernetes-model-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- begin websocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end websocket -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <mainClass>com.highgo.cloud.CloudServiceApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- mapstruct -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>public</id>
            <name>aliyun nexus</name>
            <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>public</id>
            <name>aliyun nexus</name>
            <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>


There are a circular references (you should fix that first). Second you are using an version 2.3.5.RELEASE which is long out of support (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) Also using an old JDK 1.8 version furthermore please show the content of ls -la target directory ? Also the full pom file would really help...
